# Play Framework 2.4 sending email

Tags: scala, email, playframework-2.4

I'm new to Scala and I got stuck in sending an email...

I'm working with Play! 2.4 and have to following in **build.scala**

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"
```

In application.conf the following:

```
play.mailer {
    host=smtp.gmail.com
    port=587 
    ssl=true
    tls=true
    user="testme@gmail.com"
    password=abracadabra
    debug=true
```

}

What I'm trying to do is to send an email to an user, for example user_1, when some other user, user_2, borrows a book from user_1.

In my book controller I have this methods:

```
def sendEmail(email_user: String, subject: String, msg: String): Unit = { 

    val email = Email(
      subject,
      "FROM <testme@gmail.com>",
      Seq("TO <"+email_user+">"),

      bodyText = Some(msg)
    )

}
```

In the next method I call the **sendEmail** method if user_2 borrows a book from user_1

```
  def borrowBook(id_book: Long) = Action { implicit request =>
     val nr = Book.checkBook(id_book)
     val date = new Date()      

     if(nr > 0)
     {
        val list = Book.getCarte(id_book)
        val no = Friend.isFriend(list.id_user, userInfo.id.get)
        if(no == 1){ 
         Borrow.insert(Borrow(id_book, userInfo.id.get, date))

         sendEmail(userInfo.email, "Borrow book", "Your book has been borrowed")
         Ok(views.html.borrowBook())
         }else Ok(views.html.warningBorrow())
     }
     else Ok(views.html.failBorrow())

 }
```

The problem is that I don't receive any error or something like that and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There does not seem to be any code that actually sends the email - you just create an Email case class but you never actually send it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you are actually sending the email. The sendEmail method is just creating the Email class, but it doesn't do anything else with and it doesn't return it. That does not actually send the email.

According to: https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer you are supposed to send the email by calling the `MailerClient`

The example linked shows code which basically configures the mail client to send via a particular server and then calls `mailerClient.send(email)`:

In the example, the `MailerClient` used, was injected into the controller at construction time.

Comment: Thank you! :)

At least now  I'm receiving an error 


EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

I changed the port to de default one ,25, but I'm receiving the same error...

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to your latest comment (not enough rep to comment yet) about ports: try port 465 because you have enabled both SSL and TLS. Also try to switch off debug mode (just remove the line with it). Checked your code with appropariate send method with my own google account and it worked fine.